# Make IE respect your whitespace with dynmically changed content

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, internet-explorer, whitespace

If I have the following line in html:

```
<span></span> wtf
```

and then I run the jQuery statement:

```
$("span").html("test");
```

It ends up looking like "testwtf" instead of "test wtf". Is there anything I can do about this without changing the html?

Comment: You might get better results on http://doctype.com/

Comment: $("span").html("test "); or 

$("span").html("test&nbsp;");

Comment: Thats not acceptable Anand. First of all, in other browsers, there would be an extra space. Second of all, it would then be impossible for me to omit a space in the HTML if I wanted to. This is about automating something. Clearly if I wanted to I could do it manually.

Comment: don't browsers trim away multiple spaces?

Comment: @BT - There would only be an extra space if the span is within a whitespace-preserving element (those are rare, I can only think of pre right now). Otherwise, multiple spaces are collapsed to one. So Anand's suggestion should work.

Comment: No, it won't work. If a nbsp is directly after the span, it'll improperly format it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because IE is interpreting the space in `<span></span> wtf` to be a leading space, and omits it (and interprets the HTML as `<span></span>wtf`). Because IE is interpreting the HTML differently than other browsers, I don't think there's much you can do without changing the HTML, except doing a workaround like

```
$CONTAINER.html('<span>test</span> wtf')
```

or an even more extreme workarounds such as

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie) $("span").html("test "); else $("span").html("test");
```

Edit: Preliminary testing shows that `$("span").html("test ");` by itself is also sufficient.